# CSS : Resize height of container with respect to the text

Tags: css

Not sure about the title of the question. I have a span tag which is having padding-top somehow(tried to highlight in the screenshot below with black arrow), I am not sure how to remove it. I tried with `line-height:100%` but it also had some padding-top. Although the bottom border is perfectly fine.

```
span {
    background-color: red;
    color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    font-size: 58px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4m6hbrc/)

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried different browsers and fonts?

Comment: I understand your explanation but why do you want to remove the gap? it actually comes by default.

Comment: Yes. I did try that. Browser - IE 8, Mozilla and Font - Tahoma,Verdana. But it still shows same result.

Comment: @Mr_Green: The reason for removing the gap is requirement driven where I need to calculate exact height of the span and do some manupulation.

Comment: @Shubh there there is no need to do that. you can use `span.offsetHeight` to calculate the height using javascript. if you are talking about the height of the font, then it is `58px` as you mentioned in css.

Comment: I suspect it's not padding, it's actually part of the character glyph so you probably can't remove it.

Comment: It's natural glyph spacing as part of the font. Different fonts have different amounts of glyph spacing, so you could try another. You could also reduce the `line height`, but that may cut off the ends of some letters, e.g. g, y.

Answer (score 0):

That extra space above the text can be removed by the property `line-height`.

```
line-height: 0.5em;
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9tcxosv9/1/)

Here is the snippet.

```css
span {
  background-color: red;
  color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 58px;
  line-height: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<span>Fylgpm</span>
```

Comment: I'd recommend not using span since you want to control height.  Try using div with
{ display:inline-block;   line-height: 0.9em;
  height: 60px; }

Comment: Thank you @shrinivas, but the solution will cut the font when the `font-size` increases. [e.g.](http://jsfiddle.net/2z10r0j8/)

Comment: See my comment above.  Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fj6peapk/1/